# Is there a way to expand a variable at TFS get time, specifically, the changeset ID being gotten?

Tags: tfs, version-control

I would like a unit test report to contain the ChangesetID of the unit test source file. Some source control systems (Unix sccs, PVCS) have special variables that the source control system will bind (resolve, expand) when the file is downloaded from the source control store.

```
@TestReport(originalAuthor = "RRE",
            specificationDocument = "CIP_LLSDD_Infrastructure_Common.rtf",
            classUnderTest = Actor.class,
            changeset = %%TFSCHANGESET%%
            )
```

Is there such a thing in TFS source control?

Comment: What's the exactly meaning of "expand a variable" ? Did you just mean to increase the gotten changeset ID from TFS ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: "bind" would be a better word than "expand". I have added an example usage

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such way to bind a variable as you demonstrate in TFS. Please see my update answer.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I believe you are correct. Could you remove the downvote from the question? Thanks

Comment: @RoberREvans I didn't downvote your question, stackoverflow  is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.  Even though some questions may not be so professional, but I think this is the reason why the function- _edit question_ should exist. Moreover, I have upvote your question for your well-intentioned advice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way to bind a variable as you demonstrate in TFS.

If you want to add the changeset info into an unit test report, you may have to customize it through **TFS API**.  Here is a example shows how to customize the test report for you reference: [Creating a detailed test report 
showing results of test case steps](http://fluentbytes.com/creating-detailed-test-report-showing-results-test-case-steps/)